# Range function to reduce range

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to reduce the range of a **selected column** to only contains non-blank cells by using a function.

Most of the other threads are for sub.

I'm still a beginner at VBA. I tried modifying the below code in a number of ways but I can't get it to work. How can I return the reduced range?

```
Function RangeReduce(rng As Range) As Range
    Dim first_row, last_row As Double
    first_row = rng.Cells(1, 1).Address
    last_row = rng.Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address
    Set RangeReduce = Range(first_row, last_row)
End Function
```

Comment: what do you mean by *"reduced range"*? • Note that `Cells(Rows.Count)` is invalid `cells` needs a `row` **and** a `column`, also note that if you want to store an `.Address` in a variable you must declare it as `String` and you must declare the type for **ever** variable `Dim first_address As String, last_address As String` otherwise VBA assumes `Variant` if not specified. • Don't call your variables `…_row` if you actually put an address into them, that is extremely confusing.

Comment: How are you calling this? Does the UDF work, you just don't know how to get it? You likely would do `Dim redRange as Range // Set redRange = RangeReduce(Range("A1:A100"))`.  Edit: (I can't ever remember when to use `()` or not, so maybe also try `Set redRange = RangeReduce Range("A1:A100")`)

Comment: look at using `specialcells`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Just a small point but `Cells(Rows.Count)` is not invalid, but it might not reference the cell that is expected. That is, presumably the last cell in a column. If `rng` were A1 it would work.

Comment: In order to select the blank cells, you can use this: `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select`, maybe you can use this to find a way to remove those from your selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SpecialCells` modifier (? not sure what that's called) of `Range()`.  Also, I assume you definitely have constants but may or may not have formulas.

```
Function RangeReduce(rng As Range) As Range
Dim constRng As Range, formulaRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set constRng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
Set formulaRng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
On Error GoTo 0


If formulaRng Is Nothing Then
    Set RangeReduce = constRng
Else
    Set RangeReduce = Union(constRng, formulaRng)
End If
End Function
```

And you can call like:

```
Sub t()
Dim redRange As Range
Set redRange = RangeReduce(Range("E:E"))
Debug.Print redRange.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: wouldn't `Set RangeReduce = Union(constRng, formulaRng)` throw an error if `constRng` is `Nothing`?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - Ah, yes, didn't think to account for that. I'll edit the code.  Edit: Hm, since the `UDF` returns a range, what should be returned when there *is no range*?

Comment: Thanks @BruceWayne for the proposed solution, it's working. If there is no range, can the function return `Nothing` and suppress error? I'm using the function as an input for another function.

Comment: @BruceWayne If this UDF is used as a forumla I would make it `Variant` and definitly return an error instead of `Nothing` like `RangeReduce  = CVErr(xlErrNA)`. So this can also be handled by `=IFNA()` in a formula like `=IFNA(RangeReduce(A1:B10),"Nothing to Reduce")`. If the UDF is not used as a formula then I would just return `Nothing` as this can be catched by the calling procedure easily.